# Trying to show convergence of a Forward Euler method based on step size restriction

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I have shown that for the given ODE system, that when we apply the forward Euler method to something like
\begin{align}
\mathbf{y'} &= A\mathbf{y} \\
\mathbf{y}(t_{0}) &= y_{0} \\
t &\in (t_{0},T]
\end{align}

where $A$ is diagonalizable; $A = PDP^{-1}$, that the solution given by forward Euler is
\begin{align}
u_{n} = P(I + hD)^{n}P^{-1}u_{0}
\end{align}

where we consider the Forward Euler method to be $ y_{k+1} = y_{k} + h y'(x_{k},y_{k}). $ N

Now, I want to show that if the real parts of $\lambda_{k}$ (the eigenvalues of $A$ and thus the entries of $D$) are **negative**, then $h < \frac{-2 Re\lambda_{k}}{|\lambda_{k}|^{2}}$ for all $k$ implies that $u_{n} \rightarrow 0$.

Now, in order to show this, based on what we have obtained for the formula for $u_{n}$, we need only show that for each $k$, $|1 + h\lambda_{k}| < 1$.  I am having a really tough time doing this, and have mostly just tried to play around with AM-GM stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You have to find the set $|1+z|<1$ in the complex plane. Squaring this inequality results in
$$
1+2\,Re(z)+|z|^2<1\iff Re(z)<-\frac12|z|^2
$$
Now insert $z=hλ_k$ and that $h$ is a real number...